# Matte reflection effect in Unity?

Tags: unity, shaders, reflection-rendering

I'm trying to achieve that kind of scene but in real time using Unity.

[image]

It's basically composed of some primitives, a skybox, and a plane. I'm intrigued on how to do this effect in particular:

[image]

The plane acts like a mirror, but tainted and matte (and it appears to be less blurry at the bottom of the buildings... but I'm not quite sure). I have found [some shaders to create mirrors in Unity](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/MirrorReflection4) but nothing about the matte effect like in this picture. Could you guide me on how to achieve this kind of effect (knowing that I'm pretty lame when it comes to write shaders but I want to learn).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection on a rough plane are a bit difficult, as the distance between the point observed & the object reflected into it come into play.

That mean you need to render your colors of your reflection, but also its depth, to be able then to compute for each pixel of the plane it's distance to the pixel it reflect. Then you blur it using a ratio computed from distance & roughness of the plane.

Not an easy task if you don't know shaders or post processing, but I suggest taking a look at Screenspace reflection & Physically based shading for inspiration of handling roughness & blurring. It's heavy stuff though.